# Can spark yarn default queue run jobs in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have two jobs submitted with default capability scheduler as following, but `StagingDataset` will not run until `Thrift JDBC/ODBC Server` got killed. Is there any way run two jobs in parallel in the same queue?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a setting in capacity-scheduler.xml is causing the problem.  Can you add this config file to your question?